# Is there a Way to Get index of highest candle in pine script?

Tags: pine-script

I want the index of candle that has highest high.
for example I write this code for get highest value:

```
MyHighest = ta.highest(high,3)
```

this code return the high value of that candle but i want the index of that candle has highest value.
how can i do this?

Comment: Please add your full code.

Answer (score 1):

There is `ta.highestbars()` for that.

> Highest value offset for a given number of bars back.
>
> **RETURNS**
> Offset to the highest bar.
> **ARGUMENTS**
> *source (series int/float)*: Series of values to process.
> *length (series int)*: Number of bars
> (length).

Answer (score 0):

I solved that:

`MyHighestIndex = ta.highestbars(high, 3)`